# импорт функции по умолчанию

Tags: javascript, node.js

Разъясните пожалуйста не могу понять что я делаю не правильно. Есть такой код:

Экспортирую анонимную функцию по умолчанию. Файл **flash-message.js**:

```
export default function(message){
    console.log(message);
}
```

Далее импортирую, это дело в файл **app.js**:

```
import flashMessage from './flash-message';

flashMessage("hello!");
```

И подключаю оба модуля в **index.html**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
  <script src="./flash-message.js"></script>
  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

В мануале по которому делаю, всё работает. У меня хром пишет ошибку:

> flash-message.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
>
> app.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Есть два момента, которые мне не понятны:

1. Почему в туториале, на видео, такая структура работает. И хром не выдаёт ошибок.
2. Почему если я транcлирую этот код c помощью babel ("presets": ["es2015"]). В интерпритаторе node код работает, а в хроме всё равно ошибка.

Comment: export и import ещё не введены в обработку браузерами. Обязательно код es6 нужно компилировать к примеру с помощью babel. Вам как раз и выдает ошибку, что браузер не знает о чем вы)

Comment: что за туториал?

Comment: @Василий Барбашев Я же и говорю дальше что компилирую его , после этого на ноде работает а в браузере нет

Comment: @Grundy https://www.codeschool.com/courses/es2015-the-shape-of-javascript-to-come

Comment: @stas0k проходил его, но не возникало проблем. Что значит ещё на ноде работает, а браузере нет? Нода серверная, браузер клиентская сторона. И их интерпритаторы немного отличаются. После компиляции какой код у вас браузер не понимает, добавьте в вопрос, что в сорсы приходит

Comment: А если поменять export default на module.exports?

Comment: @Василий Барбашев  Весь код представлен выше, ничего друго нет. запуская index.html в браузере и оно не работает, почему?

Comment: потому что это ES6, его надо компилить в ES3 (текущий js)